# InOrder traversal of BST...why is loop condition "cur != null || !stack.empty()" ?"

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

This is the InOrder traversal (left, root, right) for a BST:

```
public List<Integer> inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode cur = root;

    while(cur!=null || !stack.empty()){
        while(cur!=null){
            stack.add(cur);
            cur = cur.left;
        }
        cur = stack.pop();
        list.add(cur.val);
        cur = cur.right;
    }

    return list;
}
```

I cannot wrap my head around why the 'while' loop condition is cur != null || !stack.empty().

I particularly am MOST confused by "cur != null". **Why is this even necessary?**

From logic of an 'or' statement, A || B means A and B have to be both false in order for the loop to break.

So the loop will break once cur == null and the stack is empty.

Why do we even need to care if cur == null? Isn't this extraneous and not necessary?

Note: Original LC problem (for testing) -- https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only continue the loop if the stack is not empty, the loop will not start at all because the stack is empty.

Even if you use a do...while loop, the condition of "stack is not empty" is not enough.

Consider a tree without left nodes:

```
root
   \
    \
    node1
      \
       \
      node2
```

The algorithm would add `root` to the stack, then pop it, then add it to the list. After that, `curr` will be the right node of `root`, which is `node1`. At this point, the stack is empty, but `curr` is not null.

The loop would stop at this point, which is clearly not correct.

The while loop should only stop when both the stack is empty *and* there is no right node (i.e. continue if stack is empty *or* there is a right node).

Comment: From the way the code is written, I have figured out that the 'while' loop will not execute at all if you remove curr != null because stack is empty before the loop. Is this intentional or just coincidental?

Comment: @buddybuddybuddybuddy Ah that is a reason for the `curr != null` check too (and arguably more important)! I don't know how on earth I missed that. It is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Without `cur!=null` check, if you call `inorderTraversal(null);` it'll throw `EmptyStackException`.

If you are running this in any IDE like Eclipse, you can use debug feature.
Or manually try execute simple input `[1,null,2]`.
After first iteration the stack will be empty but `curr` will not be null.